# Can spring-cloud-aws using resourceLoader be used with S3 server-side-encryption using a kms key?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, spring-cloud-aws

Using AWS SDK, it can be achieved easily like this:

```
PutObjectRequest putRequest = 
       new PutObjectRequest(bucket_name, bucket_name, new File(file_path))
      .withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams("KMS-KEY"));
s3.putObject(putRequest);
```

However, can this is achieved using spring-cloud-aws with a s3 capable ResourceLoader as below ?

```
WritableResource resource = (WritableResource) resourceLoader
  .getResource(s3Url);

try (OutputStream outputStream = resource.getOutputStream()) {
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), outputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible as of now. A feature request has been created from some time now however: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/104